# Read Serial-Over-IP Data in the Browser with Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket, tcp, serial-port

I have been tasked with porting a local Windows + .NET Framework application to a frontend Javascript SPA.

The application interfaces with hardware components which communicate over serial. I understand the [Web Serial](https://web.dev/serial/) and [Web USB](https://web.dev/usb/) APIs are available here and do intend to use them for directly connected devices.

But we have many users using RS232 Serial-to-IP converters/servers to send the signal over TCP/IP.

It's my understanding a raw TCP/IP stream cannot be consumed via frontend JS.

I have researched hardware as well hoping there might be Serial-to-IP servers that support a different output stream like Websockets but haven't found any that report to do so. I'd also like to avoid asking all of our users to upgrade hardware if at all possible.

Are there any methods to achieving this in frontend-only JS?

Comment: Perhaps [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) are in the direction you're looking for? If I remember correctly they communicate over TCP

Comment: @PatrickBarr: WebSockets are not plain TCP sockets but their own protocol on top of TCP. It is not possible to implement arbitrary TCP protocols with WebSockets, instead the protocol must somehow be based on WebSockets too.

Comment: *"my understanding a raw TCP/IP stream cannot be consumed via frontend JS"* - correct. Which also answers your own question: since you want a raw TCP stream and you don't get it from front-end JS you cannot do it with front-end JS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I thought this may be the case but am not a JS expert and was hoping I was missing some new capability or API to allow.

Comment: You might try with some local program which is a WebSockets server to the browser and translates it then to a "real" TCP socket for to the Serial-To-IP, i.e. things like [websocksify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify). Not as smooth as just using the browser but maybe better then upgrading the hardware.